# Build a line between div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

What element do I need to create **black** lines in the **image** ? [![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have written code but I need lines like image (create between images) how can I do this?
Please tell me

**My codes are as follows**:

Comment: Post the code that creates an output as per the image.

Comment: you can use `col-hiw` this class and add :pseudo css

ex : `col-hiw:after{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using ":after" & ":before" you can set line between two images

```css
.hiw-content .hiw-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px;
}




div#a3:after {
       z-index: 999;
       content: '';
       width: 150px;
       background-color: black;
       /* left: 0; */
       height: 5px;
       position: absolute;
       right: -80px;
       top: 50%;
       border-radius: 100px;
}
div#a3:before {
       z-index: 999;
       content: '';
       width: 150px;
       background-color: black;
       left: -80px;
       height: 5px;
       position: absolute;
       /* right: 50%; */
       top: 50%;
       border-radius: 100px;
}

div#a3 {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-hiw col-hiw-bottom" id="a4">
            <div class="hiw-content">
              <div class="hiw-img"><img src=""></div>
              <span class="hiw-title">Customer Service</span>
              <p class="hiw-content">Let our dedicated customer service team take care of any inquiries</p>
                     
            </div>
     
          </div>
         

                <div class="col-md-4 col-hiw col-hiw-bottom" id="a3">
            <div class="hiw-content">
              <div class="hiw-img"><img src=""></div>
              <span class="hiw-title">Order fulfilled</span>
              <p class="hiw-content">Once a buyer places an order we’ll take care of order production and shipping.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
     
                   <div class="col-md-4 col-hiw col-hiw-bottom" id="a2">
            <div class="hiw-content">
              <div class="hiw-img"><img src=""></div>
              <span class="hiw-title">Boost your sales</span>
              <p class="hiw-content">Use Teesprings Boosted Network, Marketing Tools and Partnership Integrations </p>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to help you if you included more detailed code, the code above really doesn't help, to create a simple line you can do something like this (adjust margin and height/width appropriately) :

```css
.underline {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 0.25rem;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="underline"></div>
```